# Проблема с открытием портов на VM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables, port, ufw

Проблема в том что прописываю правила iptables:

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 800 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 800 -j ACCEPT
```

и ни как не могу понять почему не подключаются порты, запускаю docker на разных портах и никак не могу открыть их на внешних адресах с портами следовательно. Помогите решить проблему мучаюсь не первую неделю.

Пробовал и через ufw прописывать и через iptables

Comment: Какие правила, какая VM, какой docker, какие внешние адреса, о чём речь вообще?

Comment: VM от гугла, пробую первый раз, ну запускаю приложение с помощью докера, на другом сервере всё работает а на этом нет, правила почти одинаковые

Comment: К сожалению штатный телепат не выспался и не хочет угадывать, что там за докеры с приложениями и правилами

Comment: докер - Docker — программное обеспечение для автоматизации развёртывания и управления приложениями в средах с поддержкой контейнеризации, контейнеризатор приложений. Дело то в другом в том что бы открыть порты на сервере для доступа из вне к приложению.

Comment: И в чём проблема?

Comment: в том что при в вводе в поисковую строку http://34.70.254.62:800 это адрес по которой запущено приложение не открывается

Comment: И что конкретно вы предприняли для того, чтобы по этому адресу что-то открывалось?

Comment: записал правило sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 800 -j ACCEPT
и sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dport 800 -j ACCEPT. и конечно же запкустил приложение по этому адресу и порту

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, решена нужно было открыть Firewall сети. Открыл все порты, а правила пишутся автоматически при создании приложения